# Find the maximum value of $u$ on a closed disk $D$

Tags: complex-analysis

"Suppose that $u$ is a harmonic function in the disk $D = {z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|<2}$ and that $u(2e^{it}) = 3 \sin{2t}+1$ on the boundary circle. Without calculation find the maximum value of $u$ in the closed disk D."

I am assuming that I can use the maximum/minimum principal for harmonic functions and so am looking for the maximum at the boundary, that is the maximum value of $u(2e^{it}) = 3 \sin{2t}+1$ which must be 4 for some value of $t$.

However, I am in the habit of going on the completely wrong track when it comes to harmonic functions and contours, can someone please check whether this is right, and if I am on the wrong track give me pointers in the right direction?

Comment: At least this time, you didn't follow your habit (if it is indeed one), and instead followed the right track. It's spot-on.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the theorem:

> if $z_0$ is interior the domain $D$ of an harmonic function $f$, then
>   $$ B(z,r)\subset D \Rightarrow f(z_0) = \int_0^1 f(z_0 + r\exp{2i\pi \theta}) d\theta$$

It tells you that the maximum of $|f|$ on $D$ can't be on an inside point of the domain.